# Created a new account in my Google Admin tenant, login always redirects to Microsoft's SSO page

Tags: single-sign-on, microsoft

I have a very old Google Admin tenant from when this service was still available for free. I don't use it for email anymore; my email is hosted on outlook.com now (another now-defunct free option). I created a new user in my Google tenant, but when I try to log in as that user, it's consistently redirecting to the Microsoft SSO page. My existing Google accounts can log in just fine. I've tried in private browsing, other browsers, and other computers, and I just cannot seem to log in. Is there any known workaround for this?